# Prove that: $(A\Delta B)\Delta C = (A \Delta C)\Delta (A\setminus B)$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For sets A, B and C, prove that:  $(A\Delta B)\Delta C = (A \Delta C)\Delta (A \setminus B)$.

I've tried arbitrary element and tabular methods. Weird thing is that tabular (basically, truth table with 8 possible combinations) worked for me for the first 3 proofs of the exercise (which were pretty similar to this one) but not for this one.

When, picking arbitrary element, I try to prove the $(A\Delta B)\Delta C \subset (A \Delta C)\Delta (A \setminus B)$ containment part, and I consider the case that $x\notin C$ (which, i think, implies that $x\in A\Delta B$) i always get to the conclusion that the property does not hold, so there is clearly something i'm missing.

*Edit: I contacted the author and indeed it was an error in the exercise. The answer i marked as the most useful in this post is correct: that is the same mistake the author identified.*

*Thanks*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This claim is not true, assuming that $Δ$ is the symmetric difference operator. Consider the sets $A = \{a\}, B=\{b\}, C=\{c\}$. Then

$$(AΔB)ΔC=\{a, b, c\},$$
$$(AΔC)Δ(A∖B) = \{a,c\}Δ\{a\}=\{c\}.$$

Where was this claim made? Is it possible there was a typo in the claim? Or was there a mixture of true and false claims, with a "prove or disprove" goal?

Edit: I think there was a typo, and the claim should have been

$$(A \cap B) Δ C = (AΔC)Δ(A∖B).$$

See if you can prove that instead.

Comment: Thank you very much! It is in "Proofs: A Long-Form Mathematics Textbook". Exercise 3.41, part (e). The exercise says exactly what i wrote. Prove that it's true. I guess it is an error in the book. I read it several times, almost obsessively, because there is this page https://longformmath.com/proofs-errata where there are corrections to a lot of errors, and it is pretty surprising for me that there are even corrections in this same page, but this is not listed. I might be misreading something, but i don't think so

Comment: @Pallascat You're welcome! I think I've identified the typo, see my edit.